# Azure AD B2C Custom policy SignUp & SignIn with MFA and with force password after 90 days

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am trying to integrate this policy to my policy:
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/force-password-reset-after-90-days/readme.md

[extension_passwordResetOn custom user attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCR4R.png)

I created the required custom user attribute.
Next, I edited the extensions file and the file for signin by changing the user journey.

Note that client id and object id are deliberately set to "test" to paste the code here.

I expect that when I register a new user it will set the date to 0 and after 90 days it will ask me for a change.

at the moment if I try to make a registration when I try to submit the form with the data I get a message saying "An invalid value was presented for a property".

[An invalid value was presented for a property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whgPO.png)

I share relying party file: https://easyupload.io/a4tclj

This is my extension file:

```
  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>b2c.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkLocalization</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>
  <!--   <BuildingBlocks>
    <ClaimsSchema>
    </ClaimsSchema>
  </BuildingBlocks> -->
  <ClaimsProviders>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Facebook</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="Facebook-OAUTH">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="client_id">facebook_clientid</Item>
            <Item Key="scope">email public_profile</Item>
            <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,name,email</Item>
          </Metadata>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Token Issuer</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <!-- SAML Token Issuer technical profile -->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="Saml2AssertionIssuer">
          <DisplayName>Token Issuer</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="SAML2" />
          <OutputTokenFormat>SAML2</OutputTokenFormat>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="SamlAssertionSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SAML" />
            <Key Id="SamlMessageSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SAML" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaims />
          <OutputClaims />
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Saml-issuer" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <!-- Session management technical profile for SAML-based tokens -->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SM-Saml-issuer">
          <DisplayName>Session Management Provider</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.SSO.SamlSSOSessionProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="login-NonInteractive">
          <Metadata>
            <!-- ProxyIdentityExperienceFrameworkAppId -->
            <Item Key="client_id">1257aca9-6111-abcs-adca-d740612012fa</Item>
            <!-- IdentityExperienceFrameworkAppId -->
            <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">10f6e761-c111-dadd-acv0-affb3875cdaf</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <!-- ProxyIdentityExperienceFrameworkAppId -->
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue="1257aca9-6111-abcs-adca-d740612012fa" />
            <!-- IdentityExperienceFrameworkAppId -->
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="resource_id" PartnerClaimType="resource" DefaultValue="10f6e761-c111-dadd-acv0-affb3875cdaf" />
          </InputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId">
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-Common">
          <Metadata>
            <!--Insert b2c-extensions-app application ID here, for example: 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111-->
            <Item Key="ClientId">83axdc56-1aaa-4bbb-a666-4589cbb7a212</Item>
            <!--Insert b2c-extensions-app application ObjectId here, for example: 22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222-->
            <Item Key="ApplicationObjectId">8d93c18a-d111-4fff-8aaa-43ebedadd5b1</Item>
          </Metadata>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
  </ClaimsProviders>
  <!--UserJourneys>
  </UserJourneys-->
```

this is what is see with fiddler:

[fiddler capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yjV8.png)

Comment: You need to set up App Insights and see what's in the logs.

Comment: same extension file and relying party policy in another tenant works, so i don't understand where's the problem

Comment: @rbrayb i think that the problem is on custom attribute, there a way to verify if it's correct?

Answer (score 0):

@denisdm91 As I am not able to see the files I think you might have found the issue. If not, FYI, the custom attribute you have created a portal is of type Boolean but in policy the same is of "datetime" dataatype. You need to delete the same from portal.

Comment: Hi @mohit-agrawal 
I haven't found the problem yet, the custom attribute passwordResetOn must be boolean, the other attributes doesn't be custom. I have updated the post (and added the link to relying party file)